# Opening one shell each time

Tags: java, shell, swt

In my project i have a shell, in the shell there are 3 buttons, i want that a click on each button will open a shell ,but i want that if a shell is already open due to a click on a button then that shell will be closed and a new shell will be opened.
(I dont want 2 shell from clicking buttons to be open at the same time) 
But i have no idea how to do this.

In this class the opening of the shells should be.

```
public class ClickLabel implements MouseListener
{
        Shell shell;
        int p;
        public ClickLabel(int p)
        {
            shell = new Shell();
            this.p = p;
        }   
        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
             shell.open();              
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I dont know what to do, thats why i ask.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you need to keep track of the shells that you open - which button was clicked to open each shell, and which state they are in. This is not a place to ask people to implement stuff from scratch for you, though, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example with buttons and one active `Shell`, examine that:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    private Shell openedShell;

    public Example() {
        final Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        SelectionAdapter adapter = new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if(openedShell != null){
                    openedShell.dispose();
                }
                openedShell = new Shell(display);
                openedShell.setSize(200,200);
                openedShell.setText(((Button)e.getSource()).getText());
                openedShell.open();
            }
        };
        for(int i =1;i<4;i++){
            Button b = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH); 
            b.setText("shell "+i);
            b.addSelectionListener(adapter); 
            b.pack();
        }

        shell.pack();
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```